# Outside unit won’t work when inside blower fan spins correct way only when it is going wrong direction

Tags: electrical, hvac, air-conditioning, central-heating, heat-pump

I have a universal motor on my inside electrical unit. It runs but doesn’t have much air flow (like can barely feel anything even from the closest vent) so I swapped the direction wires and it gave me good flow, but now the outside unit won’t run. If I switch it back everything runs.

Is there a way to have it run where I get both the good flow and the outside unit will run? I am comfortable messing with wires. Thank you for your help with this.

Here is a picture of the inside part:

[image: inside part]

Comment: If you take a better picture o the schematic showing on the fan it would help.

Comment: Why is the second capacitor not connected ?

Comment: Please list the brand/model of all equipment involved as well as providing a clear, focused picture of the wiring diagram. Indicate which two wires you swapped, as well. If you want a bonus, you could include links to the installation/operation instructions for the equipment as well - this makes it even easier for someone to help you.